# Ошибка Library\PackageCache\com.unity.2d.animation@5.2.0\IK\Editor\Inspectors\IKManager2DEditor.cs(8,23): error CS0234

Tags: c#, unity3d

При создании проекта выдает такую ошибку.

[image: Ошибка]

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.2d.animation@5.2.0\IK\Editor\Inspectors\IKManager2DEditor.cs(8,23): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Animation' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor.U2D' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса